# How .on method in node js work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone explain me below code snippet? Here how and when .on method with tags "error" and "close" executes when it is not emitted anywhere.

```
    function start() {
      amqp.connect(process.env.CLOUDAMQP_URL + "?heartbeat=60", function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("[AMQP]", err.message);
      return setTimeout(start, 1000);
    }
    conn.on("error", function(err) {
      if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
        console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
      }
    });
    conn.on("close", function() {
      console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
      return setTimeout(start, 1000);
    });
    console.log("[AMQP] connected");
    amqpConn = conn;
    whenConnected();
  });
}
```

Comment: Those are events that the system can emit, not just with code.

Comment: Why do you think it's not emitted anywhere?

Comment: Because in code I can't see these events emitted. So, how this works, I mean how system know when to emit these events. If suppose I write conn.on("hello", function() { console.log("hello"); }); How system will know when to emit "hello".

Comment: @Shilpi like I said, there's pre-defined event emissions that happen behind the scenes, like connect, disconnect, close, error, etc. If you create one called "hello" that isn't pre-defined by the module, you need to manually emit it. Otherwise, the system handles that behind the scenes.

Comment: @Shilpi as Sterling said they are predefined events readily available for you to use so that you can concentrate on developing your project rather than having to design even firing for each event. If you are curious to how they are fired, you can look into the library code.